# Инроглифы в телефоне на андройде

Tags: телефония, android

Здраствуйте, нигде не могу найти, где можно изменить кодировку текста. Закачиваю на телефон музыку, английский текст норм читает, а русский иероглифами пишет.

Answer (score 1):

Поставить альтернативный плеер с поддержкой cp1251: [приручаем смартфон на Android: мультимедиа, общение, GPS-навигация](http://technoportal.ua/articles/encyclopaedia/8308.html).